# Sqoop to MySQL using Hive Query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop

I want to sqoop data from a Hive table to a MySQL table. Both have the same set of column, but their order is different.

Is there a way to sqoop data to mysql table using a Hive query which has the column order that belongs to the mysql table?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop currently do not support "export" operation from Hive query. Supported workaround is to run your Hive query that will change column order in Hive and store it's results in Hive as a temporary table. You can then export this temporary table using Sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the MySQL column order you need to `sqoop export` with the `--columns` option. For example, if your Hive table has them in order `A, B, C` then you run `sqoop export --connect ... --columns A,B,C` to tell MySQL the order it's getting the columns in. You have to use the column names of the destination MySQL table.